# How do I access a database in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Basically, I would like a brief explanation of how I can access a SQL database in C# code. I gather that a connection and a command is required, but what's going on? I guess what I'm asking is for someone to de-mystify the process a bit. Thanks.

For clarity, in my case I'm doing web apps, e-commerce stuff. It's all ASP.NET, C#, and SQL databases.

I'm going to go ahead and close this thread. It's a little to general and I am going to post some more pointed and tutorial-esque questions and answers on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reads like a beginner question. That calls for beginner video demos.

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-videos/

They are ASP.NET focused, but pay attention to the database aspects.

Comment: Very much a beginner question, thus the tag. Thanks for the link! I like the pretty pictures that move!

Answer (score 10):

MSDN has a pretty good writeup here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7ee2dwt(VS.71).aspx

You should take a look at the data-reader for simple select-statements. Sample from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) page:

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = 
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It basicly first creates a [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) object and then creates the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)-object that holds the actual select you are going to do, and a reference to the connection we just created. Then it opens the connection and on the next line, executes your statements and returns a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) object.

In the while-loop it then outputs the values from the first row in the reader. Every time "reader.Read()" is called the reader will contain a new row.

Then the reader is then closed, and because we are exiting the "using"-secret, the connection is also closed.

---

EDIT: If you are looking for info on selecting/updating data in ASP.NET, 4GuysFromRolla has a very nice [Multipart Series on ASP.NET 2.0's Data Source Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513213219/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011106-1.aspx)

EDIT2: As others have pointed out, if you are using a newer version of .NET i would recommend looking into LINQ. An introduction, samples and writeup can be found on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx).

Comment: Would be better to use a using statement around the command and the connection if it's scoped to the current method.

Comment: I agree, but MSDN seems to not to that in the beginner-articles (from wich I copy&pasted this), so I thought that would be fine.

Comment: I can see the logic of samples that don't adhere to "best practice" so as not to confuse things.  But IMHO disposing database connections is so fundamental (especially in web apps - and the OP is talking about ASP.NET), that it should always be included.  Go on, update your example :)

Comment: Learning this old method while Linq is out seems kind of pointless.  Why learn an old technology when a faster, easier, more powerful method is out there?

Answer (score 4):

The old ADO.Net (sqlConnection, etc.) is a dinosaur with the advent of LINQ.  LINQ requires .Net 3.5, but is backwards compatible with all .Net 2.0+ and Visual Studio 2005, etc.

To start with linq is ridiculously easy.

- Add a new item to your project, a **linq-to-sql** file, this will be placed in your **App_Code** folder (for this example, we'll call it **example.dbml**)
- from your server explorer, drag a table from your database into the dbml (the table will be named **items** in this example)
- save the dbml file

You now have built a few classes.  You built the **exampleDataContext** class, which is your linq initializer, and you built the **item** class which is a class for objects in the **items** table.  This is all done automatically and you don't need to worry about it.  Now say I want to get record with the **itemID** of 3, this is all I need to do:

```
exampleDataContext db = new exampleDataContext(); // initializes your linq-to-sql
item item_I_want = (from i in db.items where i.itemID == 3 select i).First(); // using the 'item' class your dbml made
```

And that's all it takes.  Now you have a new **item** named **item_I_want**... now, if you want some information from the **item** you just call it like this:

```
int intID = item_I_want.itemID;
string itemName = item_I_want.name;
```

Linq is *very* simple to use!  And this is just the tip of the iceberg.

No need to learn antiquated ADO when you have a more powerful, easier tool at your disposal :)

Answer (score 1):

topics to look at:

1. ADO.NET basics
2. LINQ to SQL
3. Managed database providers

Answer (score 1):

If it is a web application here are some good resources for getting started with data access in .NET:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/14/working-with-data-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To connect/perform operations on an SQL server db:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string connString = "Data Source=...";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString); // you can also use ConnectionStringBuilder
connection.Open();

string sql = "..."; // your SQL query
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

// if you're interested in reading from a database use one of the following methods

// method 1
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) {
    object someValue = reader.GetValue(0); // GetValue takes one parameter -- the column index
}

// make sure you close the reader when you're done
reader.Close();

// method 2
DataTable table;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(table);

// then work with the table as you would normally

// when you're done
connection.Close();
```

Most other database servers like MySQL and PostgreSQL have similar interfaces for connection and manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is an easy to follow tutorial, then you should head over to the www.ASP.net website.

Here is a link to the starter video page: http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-49.aspx

Here is the video if you want to download it: [video download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/E/B/5EBF4D5A-8B55-482A-A322-675EED8B7F45/hilo_data_final.zip)

and here is a link to the C# project from the video: [download project](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/6/936c8646-2211-48de-a0ee-5ffe06d64f3a/Data_CS.msi)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend using DataSets. They are really easy to use, just few mouse clicks, without writing any code and good enough for small apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 I would recommend skipping ADO.NET and leaping right in to LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 1):

@J D OConal is basically right, but you need to make sure that you dispose of your connections:

```
string connString = "Data Source=...";
string sql = "..."; // your SQL query

//this using block
using( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString) )
using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn) )
{
    connection.Open();

    // if you're interested in reading from a database use one of the following methods

    // method 1
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) {
        object someValue = reader.GetValue(0); // GetValue takes one parameter -- the column index
    }

    // make sure you close the reader when you're done
    reader.Close();

    // method 2
    DataTable table;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(table);

    // then work with the table as you would normally

    // when you're done
    connection.Close();
}
```